# use % operator in xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, math

i'm trying to make a function that use % operator in objective c
my function is:

```
-(void) image1:(UIImageView *)img1 
        image10:(UIImageView *)img10 
        image100:(UIImageView *)img100 
        score:(NSInteger *)sc
{
        NSInteger* s100,s10,s1;

    s100 = sc % 100;
    s10 = (sc - s100 * 100) % 10;
    s1 = (sc - sc % 10);
    NSLog(@"%d",s1);
}
```

but i got errors..
can you guide me to some solution

Comment: So what is your question? What your function is supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't implicitly create objects like that. You want s100, s10, s1 and sc all to be C-style variables, but you've declared s100 and sc as pointers, as though they were going to hold Objective-C objects. I suggest you change `NSInteger*` to `NSInteger` in both cases. Not all things starting in NS are objects.

Comment: You're completely right; I misread the source. I also missed that sc is a pointer. I'll correct my answer.

Answer (score 5):

NSInteger is a primitive type.  Depending on the environment it is either typedef'd to a 32 bit or 64 bit signed integer.

s100's declaration is

```
NSInteger* s100
```

so s100 is a pointer.  Taking the modulus of a pointer is wrong.  That line should be:

```
NSInteger s100,s10,s1;
```

And sc should probably be an NSInteger too.  If you do really want to pass a pointer to an NSInteger, you need to dereference it when you do arithmetic with it:

```
s100 = *sc % 100;
s10 = (*sc - s100 * 100) % 10;
s1 = (*sc - *sc % 10);
```